# How to make several "startx" profiles?

Tags: startx, xinit

I have an Arch Linux with i3wm now. When I need to start my i3, I just type `startx`, because in config file I have `exec i3;`. When I need to run some another graphical environment, such as Gnome, I edit my `xinitrc`.
Some graphical environments create after installing their own start-file (some not), such as `startdde` for Deepin. How could I create or configure new `xinitrc` for several desktops envs?

P.S I love logging from terminal first, so just don't want to install some login gui manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `exec "$@"` at the end of your `xinitrc`, and then execute

```
startx /path/to/xinitrc <wm> <wm-args>
```

from a tty.

`startx` interprets its first string argument as the client (`/path/to/xinitrc`, note that it has to be an absolute path), and rest of the arguments are passed to that client (wm and wm-args), which are `exec`ed by the xinitrc.

Note that startx is just an example script and you are encouraged to create another one according to your needs. The above mentioned setup should meet the requirements mentioned in the question though.

Comment: So I can simply make some alias'es with wm I would like to use. Thanks